# Section doesn't display properly on Safari (Mac)

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

**HTML:**

```
<section class="HeaderBar">
  <div id="schoolClickDiv" onclick="Sort('School', 'TechnologyProjectPlan')" class="columnHeaderDiv">
    <span id="SchoolArrowTechnologyProjectPlan" class="arrowHidden columnHeaderArrow ui-icon visibilityHidden" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
    <span>School</span>
  </div>
  <div id="dateClickDiv" onclick="Sort('Date', 'TechnologyProjectPlan')" class="columnHeaderDiv">
    <span id="DateArrowTechnologyProjectPlan" class="arrowHidden columnHeaderArrow ui-icon visibilityHidden" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
    <span>Date</span>
  </div>
  <div id="StatusClickDiv" onclick="Sort('Status', 'TechnologyProjectPlan')" class="columnHeaderDiv">
    <span id="StatusArrowTechnologyProjectPlan" class="arrowHidden columnHeaderArrow ui-icon visibilityHidden" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
    <span>Status</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now this displays perfectly on everything except for Safari on Mac.  Even Safari on windows displays this properly.  But Safari on mac will only render the top few pixels of the section.  If I click on the section, it then displays the rest of it.

**CSS:**

```
.HeaderBar {
    width: 98%;
    min-height: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: central;
    border: ridge;
    border-color: #c8c8c8;
    float: right;
    display: table;
}
.columnHeaderDiv {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
.columnHeaderDiv:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.columnHeaderArrow {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there maybe some CSS that Safari on Mac doesn't like?

Comment: Maybe you could include some screenshots or working links for us to look at?  I put it in a JSFiddle and it looked the same in both Chrome and Safari on OSX.

Comment: Shoot, I copied the wrong CSS.  I've updated it now, it should be the `.HeaderBar` css, rather than `.FormEntry`

Comment: I'll see what I can do about a screenshot, image sharing sites are blocked here though